# what does "&" means in java properties file

Tags: java, properties

what does "&" means in java properties file?

for example `CopyProjectAction_title = &Copy`.

does it equal `CopyProjectAction_title = Copy`?

Comment: does **java** have properties file?

Answer (score 0):

As far as config file concern, this is just string variable which may used in program to split later point of time where it used..

Answer (score 0):

In a Java properties file the "&" does not have a special meaning - in fact it is just another character like a, b or c. However once the key/value pair is loaded by some application the value containing the "&" can get meaning. For example there is a common usecase when the key describes a menu entry and ampersand is the key to access the entry quickly. There is also a Java Tutorial from Oracle about properties:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html

Answer (score 0):

If it is still needed

It seems that for SWT related usage (e.g. Eclipse Preference View & Run Configuration) the "&" char is used to prefix a specific char, making it underline during the rendering and selectable by keybord shortcut alt+char.